# simple restful java web service application

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I want to develop a simple application using java and RESTful web service that manages (add/delete/modify) a simple student table (Id, name, address, department).

Where i should start ?
Examples, sample code ?

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Check the spring.io building rest services tutorial.

Comment: This tutorial is pretty good http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question have many possible answers and many of them can meet your request.

I think that you need example which will lead you through entire development process for this functionality, which assumes creation of CRUD functionalities, services and tests.

You can check this [solution](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/project-student-webservice-server-with-jersey.html). It have all of this and this can be good start point for you, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

The JAX-RS reference implementation [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net) has good [example projects](https://jersey.java.net/download.html). You can learn and play with them